# Doctrine 2 - 2 decimal places on a float?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

Annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", scale="2")
 */
protected $curr_price;
```

I'm using it with Symfony 2.

And this field becomes a double in MySQL database instead of float with 2 point precision.

What am I doing wrong? I tried deleting the DB, reinserting etc...

Comment: Though not related to your question, storing prices as a floating point is (generally) a very bad practice.

Comment: Please elaborate more.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Both `precision` and `scale` properties work only with the `decimal` mapping type ([link](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/basic-mapping.html#property-mapping)). I suggest you use the `decimal` type.

As to why it's creating a double field instead of float, I'm not entirely sure. It probably has to do with being compatible with all supported databases. I see no mention of `double` mapping type so I assume they use the same type for both.

Answer (score 12):

in the *.yml

```
curr_price:
    type: decimal
    precision: 10
    scale: 2
```

Comment: could you decrypt please,if I try set 12345678901.2222, what was set ?

Answer (score 10):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", scale=2)
 */
protected $curr_price;
```

scale should be an integer, and you are using a string

Comment: According to [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#property-mapping): 

 *scale: (optional, default 0) The scale for a decimal (exact numeric) column (**applies only for decimal column**), which represents the number of digits to the right of the decimal point and must not be greater than precision.*